# Your car won't start? Don't look at me. (Another easy "What Am I?")

Tags: riddle, homonym

Another "What Am I?" riddle:

> People think I'm abhorrent,
>   but I'm just the first one they want to charge when there's been an attack!
>
> I'm just a slave to the machine, and I'll die without ever having lived!
>
> Your car won't start?  Don't look at me.  I'm not the AA.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you:

> A battery

People think I'm abhorrent, 
but I'm just the first one they want to charge when there's been an attack!

> Reference to Assault and Battery

I'm just a slave to the machine, and I'll die without ever having lived!

> Batteries are never alive, but they are considered "dead" when they run out of juice

Your car wont start?  Don't look at me.  I'm not the AA.

> Car won't start due to a dead battery, AA is a play on AA batteries and the AA car service in the UK (similar to AAA in the US)

Comment: Damn, just beat me to it!

Comment: Yah.  Had a feeling this one would be too easy.  :)   I'll accept in 6 min.  You were too fast buddy!

Comment: Also in the UK the big auto company is the AA...  I had no idea there was a AAA in the US or I'd have tried to use both.

Comment: @BrentHackers haha I was confused about that line, makes much more sense now

Comment: The "AA" gave it off

Comment: AAA is also a battery size as well, so that fits. :)

Comment: Also two more plays on words you didn't point out: "first one they want to charge" - charge a battery; "I'm just a slave to the machine" - slave starting a car, also known as jump starting.

Answer (score 3):

I first thought of

> a defibrillator

People think I'm abhorrent, but I'm just the first one they want to charge when there's been an attack!

> I, for one, don't fancy thinking about life assistance devices. But when someone has a heart attack, you'll want to quickly charge the defibrillator to reanimate her.

I'm just a slave to the machine, and I'll die without ever having lived!

> This gets quite dark, but fits a defibrillator's role from the point of view of the patient.

Your car wont start? Don't look at me. I'm not the AA.

> You can't start a car with a defibrillator, even though it bears some similitude to crocodile clips.